# changing default comment form arguments

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, conditional-tags, comment-form

I want to change the default comment form title_reply, label_submit ... just on my CPT without affecting the default comment form but I can't get it to work without affecting the default ones.

**First** I don't want to output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in, I'm doing this with this code:

```
// Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in
if ( 'myCPT' != get_post_type() || is_user_logged_in() ) {
 comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:'));
 }
```

Which is working fine, but I want also to check if CPT exists and  alter the default comment form if I'm inside that CPT. 
Now the question will be how can I put this together ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logic reads like this: "If the post type ***is not*** 'myCPT' or if the user is logged in, then use the altered `comment_form`" So, all post types except `myCPT` use the altered form and any user that is logged in will see the altered form.

That doesn't sound like your description of the problem:

> I want to change the default comment form title_reply, label_submit
>   ... just on my CPT without affecting the default comment form...

Nor does it sound like the description of what you think the code should do in the comment:

> Don't output the comment form if CPT and user isn't logged in

There are at least two descriptions of what should be happening and the code does neither-- not even close.

Assuming the simplest case that you want to change the defaults for the comment form for your CPT, then...

```
if ( 'myCPT' == get_post_type()) {
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
     comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:'));
  }
} else {
  comment_form();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need in addition to the existing code to check also if there is a CPT and alter the default comment form if that CPT exists. I've updated my question.

Comment: Edited to incorporate the what I think is the logged in logic you want.

Comment: To be more clear: I want to hide the comment form if user is not logged in and the CPT exists and if the user is logged in and CPT exists to display different title_reply

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your PHP conditional. You're saying "if A or B, then do something", but that's not what you really want to do.

Try manipulating the arguments array directly, and then passing it to the comment form:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $comment_form_args = array();

    if ( 'myCPT' == get_post_type() ) {
        $comment_form_args['title_reply'] = 'Got Something To Say:';
    }

    comment_form( $comment_form_args );
}
```

### Edit

If you don't need the `is_user_logged_in()` conditional, just remove it:

```
$comment_form_args = array();

if ( 'myCPT' == get_post_type() ) {
    $comment_form_args['title_reply'] = 'Got Something To Say:';
}

comment_form( $comment_form_args );
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one important aspect to mention, I've updated my question.

Comment: see edited answer. If you don't need the `is_user_logged_in()` conditional, just remove it.

Comment: The same, I want to keep my current **if conditional** code  and in addition to it to check for the CPT and output different title_reply within the CPT. How can I integrate your code inside the code I've posted ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to hide the comment form if user is not logged in and the CPT exists and if the user is logged in and  CPT exists to display different `title_reply`.

Comment: And what doesn't work with the code in my answer?